# Lowest tax implication for selling an inherited house

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, inheritance

**Context**: A homeowner passed away in 1999 and the house ownership was moved into a trust. At that time the house was worth ~120k. It is now worth ~400k. The beneficiaries are divided equally among 3 people (A, B, C). One of those people (A) has stayed in the house over two years since 1999. A, B and C are all in different tax brackets.

**Goal**: Person A to own the house exclusively. Person B and C be compensated for 1/3 the market value of the house each.

**Question**: 
What are the available ways to achieve the goal with the lowest tax implication to A, B and C? For example, could the trust sell the house to A and utilize the 250k 'home sale tax deduction'?

Comment: How does living in the house ‘over 2 years’ get to claim the full $250K exclusion vs a 20 year holding period? Can you be more specific about how long A lived in the house?

Comment: What does the professor say? or the book?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm not sure. I tried to search around online and saw [here](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/the-250000500000-home-sale-tax-exclusion.html) that if you lived in a house more than two years you could get that exclusion. That was a (probably dumb) example. Person A lived in the house between 2006 and 2012.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ This isn't from a professor or a book. This is a question I've asked based on real-life. If that information is relevant I can update the question to be more precise.

Comment: Exactly what kind of trust is it?

Comment: You said person A stayed in the house from 2006 to 2012.  What happened during the other years? was it being rented? or was it empty?

Comment: Shouldn't the exclusion be for living in the house 2 of the last 5 years ? 2012 is well before that.

Comment: How is the trust set up? Are proceeds from the trust required to be distributed to the beneficiaries? This is what the answer hinges on I believe.